# Only some of the files get copied from sourceFolder to destinationFolder

Tags: c#, express, xcopy

Good morning,

I'm creating a small application as part of a learning project. I'm using Visual Express 2010 and the language is C#.

I've set up two folders (destinationFolder and sourceFolder). The first one contains the following files:

```
data1.txt, data2.txt, data3.txt, data4.txt
```

The second one contains the exact same files but with "v2" written inside them.

The application is supposed to take all text files in sourceFile and copy them overwriting the files found in the destinationFolder, so that they will have "v2" written inside too.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Updater
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)        
        {
            Console.WriteLine("--- (!) APP UPDATER (!) ---");
            Console.WriteLine("press enter to begin update");
            Console.ReadLine();

            string sourceFolder = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\sourceFolder";

            Console.WriteLine("--- updating --- beginning update");

            string destinationFolder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory; // from where .exe is run

            string[] allFilesInSourceFolder = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder);
            string[] allFilesInDestinationFolder = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(destinationFolder);

            Console.WriteLine("getting data from " + sourceFolder);
            Console.WriteLine("beginning copy in " + destinationFolder);
            Console.WriteLine("");

            for (int i = 0; i < allFilesInSourceFolder.Length; i++)
            {                    
                System.IO.File.Copy(allFilesInSourceFolder[i], allFilesInDestinationFolder[i], true);
                Console.WriteLine("--- (!) updating (!) --- copying file " + i + "/" + allFilesInSourceFolder.Length);

            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("--- UPDATE FINISHED --- press enter to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }        
    }
}
```

For some reason, only data1.txt and data2.txt get copied without problems. The rest is not copied. Also, why my loop never reaches 4/4?

Comment: Do you get an error? Do you NOT get four times `updating` on your screen? Can your give is the content of your Console-output?

Comment: No, no. The files in sourceFolder have v2 written in them, while the files in destinationFolder have v1 written in them, for example. I want the files in destinationFolder to be replaced with the files in sourceFolder.

Comment: I will attach the output in 2 minutes

Comment: Ok, this is weird. All four files are getting copied now. I haven't changed anything at all. And sometimes I get the error message: "The process cannot access the file 'D:\Documents and Settings\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Updater\Updater\bin\Release\Updater.exe' because it is being used by another process." in this line inside the loop:

System.IO.File.Copy(allFilesInSourceFolder[i], allFilesInDestinationFolder[i], true);

Comment: Is your last comment a new question...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was strictly a security issue. It got resolved in the past by simply calling IT to have me added to some security group.

Answer (score 0):

In System there is a library, IO. this contains all kinds of handy dandy functions like:
File.Copy take a look inside it or checkout the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of Length <-> Count

```
for (int i = 0; i < allFilesInSourceFolder.Length; i++)
for (int i = 0; i < allFilesInSourceFolder.Count; i++)
```